# JQuery Filter or Find each item middle of ID is different

Tags: jquery, filter, find

```
$("#DynamicControlCollection_xx__value").foreach(function () { });
```

Want to get only the elements that contain this ID, but the iterator is in the middle of the ID, is this even possible in JQuery?
xx would be some number.

```
DynamicControlCollection_1__value
DynamicControlCollection_2__value
DynamicControlCollection_3__value
```

Or maybe a simple way to pull to $("[id$='DynamicControlCollection']").foreach( ... some code that contains 'value' ...)

Comment: Would it possible to tag all the elements that have these types of IDs with a specific css class, and then query on that instead?

Comment: What do you mean by `checks contains 'value' ...`?

Comment: removed the work 'checks'. Looking at a way to add classes, these controls are dynamically generated. I did not write the code for them, but do have acces ot it, may dod some refactoring. Adding classes could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.  To select an id with a unique key inside of it:**

```
$('#DynamicControlCollection_' + xx + '__value')
```

**2.  To generically loop over all ids that contain text**

```
$('[id$=DynamicControlCollection]').each(function () {
    // gets the id of this element (eg DynamicControlCollection_1__value)
    var id = $(this).prop('id');

    // gets the index_value portion (eg 1__value)
    var idx_val = id.slice(-8);
});
```

Comment: @user295734 Ah sorry about that.  The jQuery `prop` was introduced in version 1.6, and using it in newer versions is considered best practice.